# docker containers shutdown continuously

Tags: docker, ping

I follow the official tutorial of deploying docker services https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/#add-a-new-service-and-redeploy, in the first time i tried this the containers was running as expected but after that the containers shutdown and restarting (i notice that using the visualizer service provided by docker )

and when i execute the command :

```
docker stack ps getstartedlab

NAME                     DESIRED STATE    CURRENT STATE            
ERROR
getstartedlab_web.1      Running          Preparing 2 seconds ago
 \_ getstartedlab_web.1  Shutdown         Failed 4 minutes ago     
"task: non-zero exit (2)"
```

i read in this post https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3747 that the problem came from the firewall that may block the icmp, i tried to ping docker.com and i had 100% loss packet but when i ping google.com it's ok with no loss packets.

the result of `docker ps --all` is :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
9f67c82da7c7        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     2 minutes ago       Exited (2) 2 minutes ago                          getstartedlab_web.2.zcnr0ld9bioy0dffsxmn8zss5
f59e413b0780        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     4 minutes ago       Exited (2) 4 minutes ago                          getstartedlab_web.5.ymxgnsf7n8306yr8963xyyljv
9ab631c4057c        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     10 minutes ago      Exited (2) 10 minutes ago                         getstartedlab_web.5.zr3gsvgbyxs8c51fiko5h9jxp
bee5816ce1f2        dockersamples/visualizer:stable   "npm start"         15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes                 8080/tcp            getstartedlab_visualizer.1.oyiqwb5esq6zakcdtiw4txh8a
cadca594f8cd        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     24 hours ago        Exited (2) 24 hours ago                           getstartedlab_web.1.zehutsl9cefrccqrj86dz4ap7
576b1a6db0b0        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     24 hours ago        Exited (2) 24 hours ago                           getstartedlab_web.5.za9xvxpo5yvl20kha9sjcimmz
2804ebc4fc0c        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     24 hours ago        Exited (2) 24 hours ago                           getstartedlab_web.1.zlk42chspvym3jxkzs2nc8k2d
03efb2b04489        dockersamples/visualizer:stable   "npm start"         24 hours ago        Exited (255) 16 minutes ago   8080/tcp            getstartedlab_visualizer.1.qyp4egtu9vcd31kf2jxtzxko3
b85fd1600955        username/repo:tag                 "python app.py"     2 days ago          Exited (2) 2 days ago                             getstartedlab_web.5.kzrj3m5c3jgkuox0ulpszizee
```

and the 
 `docker logs 9f67c82da7c7`
  python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

exuse me for representation of the results of those commands because when i copy past the results the lines breaks, how to copy past and preserve the same displaying ?

can anyone have a fix to this problem ? thanks.

Comment: Try running a `docker ps --all` to see a failed container, then using `docker logs [container ID]` on said container. Hopefully these error logs provide us better insight. Also, are you using a cloud instance or a limited memory environment?

Comment: i use locally docker toolbox on windows 10, i created 2 virtual machines ( a swarm manager and a woker)